# Why do UIImages initialized from FileManager data have the wrong scale?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimage, alamofire

I use Alamofire to download images from a request script I wrote. I then save the image to the device and later recall it with the following functions:

```
    private static func save(image: UIImage, fileName: String) -> String? {
        let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
            do{
                try imageData.write(to: fileURL) // When the images are downloaded, they seem to have the correct scale set already. Maybe we should verify this
                if image.scale != UIScreen.main.scale {
                    print("save - image scale: \(image.scale) does not match device scale: \(UIScreen.main.scale)")
                }
                print("Saving image to file: \(fileURL)")
                return fileName // ----> Save fileName
            }
            catch{
                print("Error info: \(error)")
            }
        }
        print("Error saving image")
        return nil
    }


    private static func loadImage(_ fileName: String) -> UIImage? {
        let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        print("Loading image from file: \(fileURL)")
        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            //let image = UIImage(data: imageData) // Bad - the image will appear twice as big as it should be, and very blurry!
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: UIScreen.main.scale) // Alamofire extension...important. Make sure that images we downloaded are recalled with the right scale for our device
            return image
        } catch {
            print("Error loading image : \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

If I download a 200x200 pixel image, iOS recognizes it as a 100x100 point image with a scale of 2.0 in the iPhone 7 simulator. If I save that image and recall it without setting the scale in the UIImage initializer extension provided by Alamofire, iOS will see it as a 200x200 point image with a scale of 1.0.

Why does this occur? Is this the best practice for saving and loading images with the correct scale and resolution?

Comment: It's unclear where your issue is. Where in your code are you seeing unexpected results? What calls `save` and where does that `UIImage` come from?

Comment: jpeg file format doesn't "save" the device scale

Comment: BTW better to use `UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Why? What would the use case be for each one over the other?

Comment: from the docs `This method loads the image data into memory and marks it as purgeable. If the data is purged and needs to be reloaded, the image object loads that data again from the specified path.`

Comment: That...didn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

When loading an image from file you have to tell the correct scale factor. Only when loading from bundle/asset catalog system recognize the image scale factor for you.

Thats the code line:

```
let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: UIScreen.main.scale)
```

You tell the image scale to be interpreted as like the scale of the device. In iPhone 7 it is 2.0. On iPhone 7 Plus it will be 3.0. When loading an image from file it shouldn't be scaled by device scale. Instead you have to tell it explicitly.
Use this instead:

```
let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: 1.0)
```

Comment: I know how to get it to work right (it's in the question). What I want to know is *why* iOS loads images from file differently than from bundled resources or even over the network. When would you ever not want the scale to be applied to the image? Is this a bug or leftover from iOS3 days?

Comment: We can't exactly tell why apple do it that way. But I think that the \@2x pattern is not a standardized solution, only a xcode/apple internal standard. So if you download a file from server there is no guarantee that an \@2x image should really be interpreted as \@2x. Maybe it's wrongly named by the owner of the server. Therefore apple decided it's better to tell system exactly how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `UIImage.init(contentsOfFile:)` or other similar methods, It depends on the file name of the png resource, screen scale and other images in that directory.

I did a quick test with the following images. All images are same just different file names. Image resolutions are 200x200. Tested with iPhone 7.

#### Images folder

```
├─ Images
  ├─ image1.png
  ├─ image2@2x.png
  ├─ image3.png
  ├─ image3@2x.png
```

#### Code

```
let imagesDirectory = .... // Images directory 

if let image1 = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: imagesDirectory + "image1.png") {
    print("image1 scale: \(image1.scale)")
}

if let image2 = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: imagesDirectory + "image2.png") {
    print("image2 scale: \(image2.scale)")
}

if let image22x = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: imagesDirectory + "image2@2x.png") {
    print("image2@2x scale: \(image22x.scale)")
}

if let image3 = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: imagesDirectory + "image3.png") {
    print("image3 scale: \(image3.scale)")
}
```

#### Output

```
image1 scale: 1.0
image2 scale: 2.0
image2@2x scale: 2.0
image3 scale: 2.0
```

You can see the output of same image but with different files name :)

#### Conclusion

Save the images with appropriate postfix like @2x and @3x.